# Problems with apt in ubuntuphone

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch

I have got a Ubuntu Phone (Aquaris E4.5). I connect to it by ssh.
When I update the repositories, the console gives me this error.

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:/$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for phablet: 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release.gpg     
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release         
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg      
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid Release          
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release  
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main armhf Packages                       
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-es                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                       
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-es_ES
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-es
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en
W: No se utilizan bloqueos para el fichero de bloqueo de sólo lectura /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
W: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/ci-train-ppa-service/stable-snapshot/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Fallo al obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/ci-train-ppa-service/stable-snapshot/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

W: Fallo al obtener http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/vivid-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]

E: No se han podido descargar algunos archivos de índice, se han omitido, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar.
W: No se utilizan bloqueos para el fichero de bloqueo de sólo lectura /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

pd: Sorry. My English is very bad :-(

Comment: it is two problems:
 - The file system is "only-read" :-(
 - Not found http://ports.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe armhf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to fix, you should mount root filesystem "read write".

Execute in Terminal application (when it asks for password, try your phone unlock code):

`$ sudo su -`

`# mount -o remount,rw /`

`# apt-get update`

...
After update,
remount filesystem back to read only:

`# mount -o remount,ro /`